# Escape invalid HTML Using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sanitization

### I am using the jQuery jext editor plugin [jqueryte](http://jqueryte.com/).

I need to be able to "sanitize" the HTML output from the editor.
When pasting content from an email, it brings along all sorts of weird and wonderful markup.

eg:

```
<p class="MsoNormal">Please can you Exclude <b>blah</b> products from the free delivery rule, we would like delivery to be £20.00 ex VAT for these products.<o:p></o:p></p>
```

The above HTML seems to be valid, but the rest of the email is not.
I need to be able to keep the formatting, so can't simply escape all html entities.

The issue I have is when displaying the content, mainly.
If I was to edit the source within the editor (I will disable this feature eventually, it's just easier than copying and pasting the email), entering the following code:

```
<p class="
```

It will render the page I insert that into invalid.

I would like to remove invalid tags, such as, the above, but keep the valid ones.
For example, this:

```
<p class="
    <b>some bold text</b>
</p>
```

becomes this:

```
<b>some bold text</b>
```

It would probably be better to actually correct the invalid HTML but this is probably harder to accomplish.

I have thought about finding an editor that uses shortcodes, such as, Stack Overflow, but this wouldn't allow me to copy and paste formatted emails.

Comment: Does invalid tag removing means any tag which does not fall in html tagscategory ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like only valid HTML5 tags to be left and the rest to be removed.

Comment: It's not clear from your description, but are you trying to sanitize this code server-side or client-side?

Comment: I'm using jQuery/Javasscript, so, client side.